# How to write this LIST in a CLASS instead of Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, code-behind

I have this **working** method in **code-behind** which gets users & their roles:

```
//code-behind working fine
private void DisplayUserAndRolesInGrid()
{
    using (myDB dataContext = new myDB())
    {
        var UserRole = (from u in dataContext.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Roles")
                        from r in u.aspnet_Roles
                        where r != null
                        select new { User = u, Role = r }).ToList();
        grdUserRoles.DataSource = UserRole.ToArray();
        grdUserRoles.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But I need to place it in a **class** & return a List, so I did following which throws below error (I guess I need to somehow modify this line: public List<aspnet_Roles> GetUserAndRoles()):

```
//in a Class with error
public class UsersClass
{
    public List<aspnet_Roles> GetUserAndRoles()
    {
        List<aspnet_Roles> UserRoles = new List<aspnet_Roles>();
        using (myDB dataContext = new myDB())
        {
            UserRoles = (from u in dataContext.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Roles")
                            from r in u.aspnet_Roles
                            where r != null
                            select new { User = u, Role = r }).ToList();
        }
        return UserRoles;
    }
}
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Please I'm stuck on this.

Comment: With select new, you're creating an anonymous object, and assign it to a list of aspnet_Roles. So it advises you about that.

Comment: If aspnet_Roles object is composed with User and Role properties .. select new aspnet_Roles {User = u, Role = r} ...

Comment: @Saledan Thanks for coming by. Error: 'aspnet_Roles' does not contain a definition for 'User' | 'Role'.

Comment: ok. If your function return a list of aspnet_Roles you have to create an object using properties allowed in that type. Otherwise you can create your class MyRole with two properties and then use it .. public List<MyRole> GetUserAndRoles .... select new MyRole { ...

Comment: could you show your aspnet_Role class pls?

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for coming by. aspnet_Role class is just an auto generated class when I created the EntityModel.edmx. It contains definition for the columns of aspnet_Roles table.

Comment: I understand this. Could you show it please?

Comment: @Sergey sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Sq8.png Guys instead of using List<aspnet_Roles> I'll try to create a custom Users class then use it as: public List<UsersClass> GetUserAndRoles()

Comment: Similar error if I use List<UsersClass> (a custom class with just fields definitions).